# Issues in integrating ios app with twitter api

Tags: iphone, ios4, twitter, integration, callbackurl

Im using xcode 4.2 for developing apps for ios 4.2 and later, so I didn't use ios5 twitter framework.
I referred a tutorial and downloaded the source code from [the site](https://mobiletuts.s3.amazonaws.com/75_twitter-api-iphone/X4-TwitterRushProjectCode.zip).

kOAuthConsumerKey and secretkeys were placed in the code, and the project runs fine and asks permissions to authorize the app.

if The username and password given correctly and the authorize button gets clicked, it went to a webpage that was specified as the callbackurl while creating the twitter app for this ios app.

I also tried with [Sharekit](http://getsharekit.com/).But, same issue occurs.
What's the problem with it, I think callbackurl should be my own organisation's website link. Why that page is called when executing.what I have to change in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the Sharekit for tweet on Twitter then some changes in sharekit.

Refere this link :http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/91895-sharekit-twitter-in-ios-5.html

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution, try https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController